# Google Chrome stopped working and won't open

Tags: ubuntu, chrome, elementary-os, pantheon

I'm using Elementary OS 0.3.4 Freya 64 bits. I was just doing okay, but all of a sudden google chrome stopped working. I tried opening again but it just won't work. I uninstalled using `sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable` and installed it again with the .deb from the official website, but nothing works.

I then tried launching it from the terminal and this is what I get:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
[19712:19712:0801/205511:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(261)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[19712:19712:0801/205511:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(261)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[19712:19712:0801/205511:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(261)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[19712:19712:0801/205511:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(261)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[19712:19712:0801/205511:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(261)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
Bus error (core dumped)
```

I didn't install any update, it just stopped working and never open again. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I get the same bus error. I tried --disable-extensions with same results. I also tried the current (dev) version with the same result. I am getting a different error message prior to the bus error:ERROR:nss_util.cc(842)] After loading Root Certs, loaded==false: NSS error code: -8018 A search for NSS error -8018 did not turn up anything yet.

Answer (score 3):

this should work for you ( change i386 to your requirements)

```
sudo apt-get install  gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386
```

and then `install` the chrome again..

credit should go to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625285/google-chrome-wont-start-unable-to-locate-theme-engine-in-module-path-adwai).. quite a detail answer lies in same question which I linked here

Comment: This may solve the original poster's issue. Unfortunately, not mine. I already have that package installed ("gtk2-engines-pixbuf is already the newest version (2.24.30-4).") I guess the only common is the Bus error. But I upvoted you for the effort.

Comment: Ok do me a favor, can you try installing dev version?? possibly  after manualy deleting the chrome folders `rm /path/to/chrome/installation/`,

Comment: I tried the dev version a few days ago. It did not help. I did not manually remove files though, just used the package manager.